# Sending Emails to Gmail, Yahoo, Outlook

Tags: c#, email, outlook, .net-4.5

I'm having troubles getting emails to send from my TCP Client. I can get emails to send to any `Gmail` or `Yahoo` email but I can't get them to send to an email that was created on the `Microsoft Exchange Server` (accessing via `Outlook` app) and I don't know why.

Here is the code that I am using to send the emails currently:

```
public void SendEmail(byte[] request)
{
    using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient(this.Hostname, this.Port))
    {
        using(var stream = client.GetStream())
        {
            stream.Write(request, 0, request.Length);
            stream.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

This sends it to the `Gmail` or `Yahoo` but not `Outlook`

The byte[] request is created via this function:

```
protected byte[] EncodeMessage(kMessage message)
{
    if (message == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("message");

    // Encode the message.
    Asn1BerEncodeBuffer buffer = new Asn1BerEncodeBuffer();
    message.Encode(buffer);

    // Write the encoded message to a byte array.
    byte[] result = null;
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        buffer.Write(stream);

        result = stream.ToArray();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Where both `kMessage` and the `Asn1BerEncodeBuffer` extend `Asn1Type`

HostName is the `IP Address` in string form of the client server. I have also confirmed that I can send an email to an email address on the outlook exchange server using Windows Powershell and a `telnet` test so it seems to be something within my code that isn't allowing it to be sent.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [SMTPClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to send emails. This is also able to get all the authentications right.

Furthermore you have to install/enable the SMTP channel in Exchange.

Comment: Is there a reason that I can't use `TcpClient`? If not, I'd rather stick with `TcpClient`. And, if I can send emails to the Exchange with PowerShell, would it not already be instealled/enabled? I honestly don't know.

Comment: If you can send emails to Exchange via SMTP with any client than it is enabled - good. You need special permissions/authentication for Exchange anyway, I think it is too much hazzle to try to reinvent the wheel here. Also I think this security code os rather complex. SMTPClient will do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Also keep in mind that by default Exchange only accepts TLS connections when sending through SMTP.